# TextField's .focused modifier not working when "out of view" SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-texteditor

I'm working with a SwiftUI `List` with a `TextEditor` at the bottom of the `List`. The `TextEditor` becomes active or "Focused" when a button is pressed.

[image]

To achieve this, I have added a `.focused` modifier to the `TextEditor`. When the `List` is scrolled to the bottom and the `TextEditor` is visible this works as expected and shows the keyboard when the button is pressed.

But the problem is that when the `List` is scrolled to the top and the `TextEditor` is not visible on the screen the `TextField` doesn't seem to get focused.

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {

    var array = Array(0...20)

    @State private var newItemText : String = ""

    @FocusState var focused: Bool

    
    var body: some View {
         
            VStack{
                List{
                     ForEach(array, id: \.self) {
                         Text("\($0)")
                     }
                     
                    TextEditor(text: $newItemText)
                        .focused($focused)
                        
                }
                Button {
                    focused = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Add Item")
                }
                
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: List does not keep all rows, so nothing non-expected here: there is just nothing in view hierarchy to get focus. TextEditory will be inserted into List only when it get scrolled close to visible area (-1 row).

Comment: I didn't know that's how it worked. So I guess scrolling to this the last row and then toggling the focused bool as @Alexander Thoren suggested is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the field in a DispatchQueue.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var array = Array(0...20)
    
    @State private var newItemText : String = ""
    
    @FocusState var focusedField: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollViewReader { scrollView in
                List {
                    ForEach(array, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                    
                    TextField("", text: self.$newItemText)
                        .id("TextEditor")
                        .focused($focusedField)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    scrollView.scrollTo("TextEditor")
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        self.focusedField = true
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("Add Item")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Hope this solves your problem!